# No pending explicit migrations even though a new record added in seed method

Tags: entity-framework

I added a new record in seed method to enter into existing sql table but when I do the update-database in PM console it doesn't do anything and gives me a message

No pending explicit migrations

```
public class ContextSeedInitializer : CreateDatabaseIfNotExists<Context>
{   
    protected override void Seed(Context context)
    {
        context.List.AddOrUpdate(
            new Names { name= "A", studentID = 1, Date = DateTime.Parse("2015-06-25")}, 
            new Names { name= "B", studentID = 2, Date = DateTime.Parse("2015-06-25")}, 
            new Names { name= "C", studentID = 3, Date = DateTime.Parse("2015-06-25")},
        );
        context.SaveChanges();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

That Seed() will only be called when the database is first created (CreateDatabaseIfNotExists). You could change your initializer to DropCreateDatabaseIfModelChanges or MigrateDatabaseToLatestVersion in order to have that seed run. You could also setup database migrations and use the Seed() method in DbMigrationsConfiguration. http://blog.oneunicorn.com/2013/05/28/database-initializer-and-migrations-seed-methods/

Comment: how to set up Seed method in DbMigrationsConfiguration. I don't want to run seed method all the time. When there is a change in table , it should run and update the data

Comment: Seed() in DbMigrationsConfiguration runs every time you do a migration. Seed() in your initializer depends on what initializer you use (see article above).